# Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) objective-c

Tags: objective-c, xcode7

> duplicate symbol _DiaryEntryMood in:
>       /Users/oluwatobiomotayo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Diary-gtbeklakdcvgxzbvjrjqjlaquthf/Build/Intermediates/Diary.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Diary.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/NewEntryViewController.o
>       /Users/oluwatobiomotayo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Diary-gtbeklakdcvgxzbvjrjqjlaquthf/Build/Intermediates/Diary.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Diary.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/DiaryEntry.o
>   ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker
>   command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

What could the problem be?
I only defined DiaryEntryMood in the NSManagedObjects subclass

```
NS_ENUM(int16_t, DiaryEntryMood){
DiaryEntryMoodGood = 0,
DiaryEntryMoodAverage = 1,
DiaryEntryMoodBad = 2
```

};

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution after the problem kept re-occuring: I just replaced

```
NS_ENUM(int16_t, DiaryEntryMood) {
```

with this

```
typedef NS_ENUM(int16_t, DiaryEntryMood) {
```

Answer (score 2):

The error reveals clearly that the symbol `DiaryEntryMood` is declared in both `NewEntryViewController` and `DiaryEntry`.

Check it and remove one of the declarations.

Comment: I can't see that i only defined DiaryEntryMood once as an NS_ENUM NS_ENUM(int16_t, DiaryEntryMood){
    DiaryEntryMoodGood = 0,
    DiaryEntryMoodAverage = 1,
    DiaryEntryMoodBad = 2
};

Comment: Press ⇧⌘F and type `DiaryEntryMood`, there must be a second declaration in the `NewEntryViewController` file

Comment: I already did that, the search result just from the enum declaration

Comment: Then try to clean the build folder: ⌥⇧⌘K and if this does not fix it quit Xcode, delete the appropriate folder related to the project in `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/` and reopen Xcode